# Android table layout: border?

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to have a border around a layout but can’t seem to make it work . Here’s what I have, and I’m trying to get something like the border shown on this.

[image]

[image]

My XML is this:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="220dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:background="#B79494"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false">
        android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:width="4dp"
        android:background="#C5BBBB"

       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/homeTest1"
            android:layout_width="47dp"
            android:layout_height="54dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="0.25dip"
            android:text="Space Line" />

          <TextView
             android:id="@+id/SowTest1"
             android:layout_width="25dp"
             android:layout_height="30dp"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:padding="0.25dip"
             android:text="A test"
             android:textSize="12sp">
         </TextView>

        </TableRow>

 </TableLayout>
```

Amy help please?
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this:

1. Place your TableLayout inside of a Relative Layout for better results i.e. Relative Layout is the parent of TableLayout.
2. Then add the background color as Black to your Relative Layout.
3. Add an equal margin of 10dp or so as per your req. To your TableLayout.

Comment: Is your problem fixed with this solution?

Comment: That's great! Thanks!

Comment: Please accept the ans so that others may know the solution for it.

Comment: Accept the ans if it was useful then.